# JObject.Parse modifies end of floating point values

Tags: json.net

```
var clientString = "{\"max\":1214.704958677686}";

JObject o = JObject.Parse(clientString);

var jsonString = o.ToString();
```

---

contents of jsonString:

```
{
  "max": 1214.7049586776859
}
```

this is both in visualizing the object and in doing ToString(). Note that the 686 has mysteriously been expanded to 6859 (precision added). This is a problem for us because the numbers are not exactly the same, and a hash function over the json later does not match.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebAPI, JSON.Net and losing decimal precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855746/webapi-json-net-and-losing-decimal-precision)

Comment: this has nothing to do with currency culture. not a duplicate.

Comment: yes, not exactly the same issue, although it could be if you were parsing to decimal instead of double. I answer your question below.

Answer (score 10):

[@Ilija Dimov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26488446/497356) is correct--JSON.NET parses JSON floats as `double`s by default. If you still want to use `JObject` instead of creating a full blown POCO for deserialization, you can use a `JsonTextReader` and set the `FloatParseHandling` option:

```csharp
var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(clientString));
reader.FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal;

JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);

Console.WriteLine(obj["max"].Value<decimal>()); // 1214.704958677686
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason your value is changed is because of the nature of floating point numbers in .NET. The `JObject.Parse(clientString)` method at some point executes the following line:

```
double d;
double.TryParse("1214.704958677686", NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d);
```

where `d` represents the number that you get in the `JObject`.

As `d` is of type double and double is floating point number, you didn't get the value you expect. Read more about [Binary floating point and .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx).

There is an option in JSON.NET for parsing floating point numbers as decimals and get the precision you need, but to do that you need to create custom class that matches your json string and deserialize the json. Something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("max")]
    public decimal Max { get; set; }
}


var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(clientString, new JsonSerializerSettings
          {
              FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal
          });
```

By using this code sample, the value of `max` property won't be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can experiment this behaviour just by parsing to float, double and decimal:

```
Assert.AreEqual(1214.705f,float.Parse("1214.704958677686"));
Assert.AreEqual(1214.7049586776859, double.Parse("1214.704958677686"));
Assert.AreEqual(1214.704958677686, decimal.Parse("1214.704958677686"));
```

So json.net is using double as an intermediate type. You can change this by setting [FloatParseHandling option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617963/json-net-primitive-types-use-decimal-instead-of-double).