# HttpClient ReadAsStringAsync rounding decimal

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

In one of the Net API controllers, I have an action which sends the request to another third party API and after receiving a response it does some manipulation with the JSON data received and finally returns the response to the frontend application. Sample code is given below:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync(_remoteServiceEndPoint + "student/" + id);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //do something with contents and finally return response to the caller
    }
}
```

Now if the third party sends a JSON response which contains a number like `999999999999999.99` and the `ReadAsStringAsync` executes in the above code snippet, it changes the value to `10000000000000000`. Which I don't want.

I would like to know why `ReadAsStringAsync` is behaving like this.

Comment: Are you sure the call to `ReadAsStringAsync()` is causing the problem? I'd suspect that to work fine, but you'd get a problem when deserializing the string with NewtonSoft.

Comment: This sounds like a bug that should be reported in the corefx repo, but I agree with Jesse - I can't see any reason why `ReadAsStringAsync` would ever need or want to modify the data it's retrieving.

Comment: @JessedeWit My bad. It's `JObject.Parse(contentString)` causing the issue.

Comment: @AJQarshi Great, I was sweating a bit for all the calls to `ReadAsStringAsync` I'd written in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JessedeWit for pointing out that it's an issue with NewtonSoft library. Introducing the workaround mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26488559/641103) SO question response solved the issue.