# How to avoid Newtonsoft JObject.Parse type conversion

Tags: c#, parsing, json.net

When I parse a String that contains a valid RFC3339 datetimestring, JOject.Parse() automatically makes an implizit type conversion to DateTime:

```
String toParse = "{\"datetime\": \"2020-08-04T23:45:00+02:00\"}";
JObject p = JObject.Parse(toParse);
String d = (String)p["datetime"];
Console.Write(d);
// Gives 08/04/2020 23:45:00
// But I want 2020-08-04T23:45:00+02:00
```

I think the "unwanted" typecast takes place while reading the `p["datetime"]` and not during `JOject.Parse()`, but how can I totally avoid that behavior and let it only deserialize everything as string?

I have this problem with different types, also decimals which are automatically casted, by I need them as String.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Json.NET Disable the deserialization on DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856694/json-net-disable-the-deserialization-on-datetime)

Comment: There is `Value<T>()` method

Comment: ... I closed this as a duplicate, then I saw your final sentence: *I have this problem with different types, also decimals which are automatically casted, by I need them as String.*  Unfortunately there is no way to get the original text for a JSON number using Json.NET.  Best you can do is to parse then as `decimal` rather than `double` using `FloatParseHandling.Decimal`, see [JObject.Parse modifies end of floating point values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26484176/3744182).  Do you want me to reopen it?

Comment: Only suggestion I can give is to switch to [tag:system.text.json] which **does** preserve the raw text for numeric values unchanged.

Comment: DateParseHandling.None and FloatParseHandling.Decimal solved my problem.
Thanks a lot!